# userEvent.click() -> 'No more mocked response for query' when testing Apollo Client with testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, vitest, testing-library

```js
describe('<UserTable />', () => {
    const gqlMock: Array<MockedResponse> = [
        {
            request: {
                query: QUERY_USER_LIST
            },
            result: {
                data: {
                    getUserList: [
                        {
                            userId: 'testuser',
                            userName: 'testname',
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            request: {
                query: VALIDATE_TOKEN
            },
            result: {
                data: {
                    validateAccessToken: true
                }
            }
        },
    ]

    beforeEach(() => {
        render(
            <MockedProvider mock={gqlMock} addTypename={false}>
                <MemoryRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path={'/'} element={<UserTable />} />
                    </Routes>
                </MemoryRouter>
            </MockedProvider>
        )
    })

    it('user display test', async () => {
        await waitFor(() => {
            const testuser = screen.getByText('testuser')
            expect(testuser).toBeInTheDocument()
        })
    })

    it('add popup test', async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            const addButton = screen.getByText('Add new user')
            expect(addButton).toBeInTheDocument()
            await userEvent.click(addButton)
        })

        await waitFor(() => {
            const popupTitle = screen.getByText(/This dialog/i)
            expect(popupTitle).toBeInTheDocument()
        })
    })
})
```

First test have no problem, but second test shows error

```
No more mocked responses for the query: query validateAccessToken {
  validateAccessToken
}
Expected variables: {}

This typically indicates a configuration error in your mocks setup, usually due to a typo or mismatched variable.
```

My system checks jwt token at every request. it is made with async-await to check token at server and do other jobs after tokens checked.

problem is that it always shows error with empty expected variables when click event is used

```
userEvent.click()
```

why this happens for every tests with click event?

Answer (score 0):

You indicate:

> My system checks jwt token at every request

Is it possible that you're issuing multiple requests in your second test?

You need to a mocked request and result for every time your query fires, including refetches.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in Apollo, where if your component requests the same mock again it doesn't find it. The simple solution is to repeat the mock again.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    render(
        <MockedProvider mock={[...gqlMock, ...gqlMock]} addTypename={false}>
            <MemoryRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path={'/'} element={<UserTable />} />
                </Routes>
            </MemoryRouter>
        </MockedProvider>
    )
})
```